# jquery: fly image src into another location?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a fly affect using jquery. Basically, when an `img` is clicked, I need the `src` of img to fly to another location on the page!

This is what I have done so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/judm6c1k/

But I don't understand why it doesn't work!

I looked into the console and I get this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).attr(...).eq is not a function
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: what's eq(0) supposed to do?

Comment: you are having console errors... fix them

Comment: you need to clone the DOM element not its attribute http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/soczcqcw/

Comment: @DarrenSweeney LMAO... i should've explained it better. basically I need the image to fly to the position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.round').click(function() {
   var cart = $('.shopping_bg');
   var imgtofly = $(this); //select the clicked object
    if (imgtofly) {
        var imgclone = imgtofly.clone()
            .offset({ top:imgtofly.offset().top, left:imgtofly.offset().left })
            .css({'opacity':'0.7', 'position':'absolute', 'height':'150px', 'width':'150px', 'z-index':'1000'})
            .appendTo($('body'))
            .animate({
                'top':cart.offset().top + 10,
                'left':cart.offset().left + 30,
                'width':55,
                'height':55
            }, 1000); //remove easing
        imgclone.animate({'width':0, 'height':0}, function(){ $(this).detach() });
    }
    return false;
});
```

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0qqgwy9/)

Comment: lol, well STO says don't say "thank you" etc so I use those words instead to express my gratitude :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the current object which is clicked, not its attribute because you are trying to clone that element so use `var imgtofly = $(this);` instead of `var imgtofly = $(this).attr('src').eq(0);`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/judm6c1k/4/)

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).attr('src')` will get your clicked image `src`

Comment: Also, after replacing this variable value, you need to replace imgtofly used lately with a variable hook to your jquery element. Now you reference an attribute value, not a jquery element, so it will throw more errors afterwards